# Unable to connect to mysql container on Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to containerize an Asp.Net Core application using Docker but on `docker compose up` aspnet app logs `Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts` and exits. I've read that Docker uses it's own internal network and provides DNS to connect to other container, so I use mysql service name in connection string, but it still doesnt connect.
It was working, when I only used docker to run mysql container, and exposed port 3306 to host, but for some reason it doesnt work now. What am I missing?
docker-compose

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ctox_db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 019638
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks: 
      - ctox_net  

  ctoxweb:
    build: .
    depends_on: 
      - mysql
    environment: 
      - "ConnectionStrings:AppContext=server=mysql; port=3306; database=ctox_db; user=root; password=019638"
    links:
      - mysql  
    networks: 
      - ctox_net  

volumes:
  mysqldata:      

networks:
  ctox_net:
    driver: bridge
```

Startup.cs

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // other services ...
    var appContextConnection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppContext");
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
        options
            .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
            .UseMySql(appContextConnection, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(appContextConnection)));
}
```

PS I added environment variables to configuration, connection string is pulled correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was not in the docker-compose or web app but in the mysql container. I thought that `depends_on` would magically wait for mysql server to start and be ready to receive connections, however as documentations suggests ([Control startup](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)) developer should rather depend on application itself to wait for database and try to reestablish connection.
For someone who needs a quick fix that might be acceptable on small projects (**be aware, it's not recommended**) just add `restart: on-failure` to your web app in docker-compose file